# Using INDIRECT() with INDEX() function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which I am hoping to build on to be able to drag down to auto complete for a number of rows.

```
=COUNTA(INDEX(1:100,0,ROW(A1)))
```

The aim of this formula is to count the number of non blank cells in each of my columns. I am aware that I could use another formula...

```
=COUNTA(EIM!A$1:A$100)
```

... and drag this across, paste special values and then paste special transpose it, but I was wondering if there was another (more elegant) way. As you can see in the second formula, I am tring to pull the values of another worksheet. Therefore, I was thinking INDIRECT() being the way to go.

My question is: How can I use INDIRECT() to combine with my first formula that uses the INDEX() function to make this happen?

*Below is a screenshot of current formula as it evaluates (not sure if it helps):*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If i understand correctly, `=COUNTA(INDEX(EIM!$1:$100,0,ROW(A1)))` should do the trick

Comment: @chrisneilsen beat me to the non-indirect answer. If you can avoid indirect, you should do so.

Comment: Hey guys I, appreciate they help. The thing is, I am trying to create a summary page that draws on a number if sheets. Therefore, using an indirect to reference the sheet name was the way I was wanting to go. FYI: In the end, I used a work around with a helper column and the formula =COUNTA(INDIRECT(A2&"!"&ADDRESS(1,F2)&":"&ADDRESS(100,F2)) where F2 had the column number and A2 had the sheet name which allowed me to drag the formula down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you *could*, but should you?

To do it, you'd use R1C1 style, by specifying `false` in indirect:

`=COUNTA(INDIRECT("EIM!R1C"&ROW(A1)&":R100C"&ROW(A1),FALSE))`

or just:

`=COUNTA(INDEX(INDIRECT("EIM!$1:$100"),0,ROW(A1)))`

**Often, if you're using INDIRECT you're doing something wrong.** The only reasonable use-cases for indirect I've seen are (a) choosing another worksheet by formula (for which there is no good way in Excel) and (b) writing an Excel tutorial example that references a named cell.

If you are always referencing a particular worksheet, you'd use:

`=COUNTA(INDEX(EIM!$1:$100,0,ROW(A1)))`

If each column represents a different worksheet, then indirect might be acceptable.

Comment: Great post. Totally forgot about the non-VBA R1C1 reference style. Although the workaround I used (see previous comment) worked, your answer worked a treat. Ps as mentioned above, I needed the indirect to reference several other worksheets. Therefore =COUNTA(INDIRECT(A2 & "!R1C"&ROW(A1)&":R100C"&ROW(A1),FALSE)) where column A has my sheet names was my ideal solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: I know that INDIRECT allows dynamic reference to a range, does INDEX behave in the same way?

Comment: Ex. =IFNA(MATCH(G2, INDIRECT($K$2), 1), MATCH(G2, INDIRECT($K$2), -1))